# xor operator find the number which appears once explain

Tags: java

I don't understand this algorithm.

For the array given in the program, if

```
i = 0, num = num ^ arr[0] => num = 0 ^ 3 = 3
i = 1, num = num ^ arr[1] => num = 3 ^ 1 = 2
i = 2, num = num ^ arr[2] => num = 2 ^ 5 = 7
...etc...and the last result in num will be printed.
```

What's going on here? How did it delete the numbers with the same value?

This algorithm finds the element that only appears in the array once, but how?

```
class Ideone {

    public static int a() {

        int arr[] = {3,1,5,1,5,3,4,7,7};
        int num = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            num ^= arr[i];
        }

        return num;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        System.out.println(a());
    }
}
```

Comment: Irina, let me know if my answer makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The other answers are `completely right`, but I think I have a nice way to think about it so I'll share my thoughts with you.

> This is a really long read, but it is super simple and I think that it will help anyone understand this algorithm and what `^`, or XOR, does.

---

> ## The easy way!

**Remember these rules!**

`n ^ n = 0`
`n ^ 0 = n`

and `n` can be **any** number.

For example:

```
1 ^ 1 = 0
1 ^ 0 = 1

6 ^ 6 = 0
6 ^ 0 = 6

12345 ^ 12345 = 0
12345 ^ 0 = 12345

0 ^ 1 = 1
0 ^ 6 = 6
```

See that the rule is [commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property).

So with these two rules, we can say that something like this:

```
n ^ n ^ n ^ n ^ n ^ n = 0
```

Why? Because:

```
n ^ n ^ n ^ n ^ n ^ n
```

is the same as:

```
(n ^ n) ^ (n ^ n) ^ (n ^ n)
```

And we've already seen that `n ^ n = 0` right?

So we are saying:

```
0 ^ 0 ^ 0
```

and since `0 ^ 0 = 0`, we get:

```
0 ^ 0
```

and since `0 ^ 0 = 0`, we get:

```
0
```

We can also say that something like this:

```
n ^ n ^ n ^ n ^ n ^ n ^ n = n
```

Why? Because:

```
n ^ n ^ n ^ n ^ n ^ n ^ n
```

is the same as:

```
(n ^ n) ^ (n ^ n) ^ (n ^ n) ^ n
```

And we've already seen that `n ^ n = 0` right?

So we are saying:

```
0 ^ 0 ^ 0 ^ n
```

We have another case of `n ^ n = 0` here since `n` can be any number, even 0! So `0 ^ 0 = 0`. Let's replace our `0 ^ 0` with what it is equal to, `0`. At the same time, we see another rule we can use: `n ^ 0 = n`

```
0 ^ 0 ^ 0 ^ n  ==  
(0 ^ 0) ^ (0 ^ n)  ==
0 ^ n
```

And of course, we've seen this rule before: `n ^ 0 = n`.

We know finish with:

```
0 ^ n = n
```

If we had just one more `n` when we started, it would have carried down to this point and we would have: `0 ^ n ^ n` which would become either `n ^ n` or `0 ^ 0`, both of which would become just `0`.

Now, we can see from the example above that when we perform `^` on any number of a certain number (like 7 n's or 20 n's, etc), we can pair these numbers and cancel them out.

We group pairs of a number, like `n`, together and they become 0. No matter how many pairs there are!

This

```
n ^ n ^ n ^ n ^ ......... ^ n ^ n
```

becomes

```
(n ^ n) ^ (n ^ n) ^ ......... ^ (n ^ n)
```

which becomes

```
0 ^ 0 ^ .......... ^ 0
```

which becomes

```
0
```

If we had an odd number of `n`'s however, like here:

```
n ^ n ^ n ^ n ^ ......... ^ n ^ n
```

it would become

```
(n ^ n) ^ (n ^ n) ^ ......... ^ (n ^ n) ^ n
```

which would then become

```
0 ^ 0 ^ .......... ^ 0 ^ n
```

which becomes

```
0 ^ n
```

which is of course, as we've said so many times:

```
n
```

---

### What does this mean?

This means that any number of a given number, `n`, when `^`'d together, will either be `n`, or `0`, depending on if we had an even or odd number of `n`'s.

An even number of `n`'s `^`'d together give us `0`, while an odd number of `n`'s `^`'d together give us `n`.

We saw this earlier when we had

And again when we had 7 `n`'s. We made 3 pairs out of the first 6 `n`'s, and had just one left over. So we ended up with a lot of 0's and one `n`. Then of course `n ^ 0 = n`.

So with any odd number of `n`'s, you'll end up with a lot of `0`'s from the pairs, and one single `n` left over. Then you'll have `0 ^ n` or `n ^ 0` (same thing), which is of course, `n`.

With any even number of `n`'s, you'll pair every two together, which will each become 0. Then you have a bunch of `0` which is of course only going to end up being `0`.

---

### Applying these rules to the algorithm

Now we can make two new rules from what we just deduced:

`n ^ n ^ n ^ n ^ ..... ^ n ^ n = 0` for any even number of `n`'s
`n ^ n ^ n ^ n ^ ..... ^ n = n` for any odd number of `n`'s

If we are working with a bunch of different numbers, the rules still apply.

Let's look at some real numbers now. Say we have:

```
3, 1, 5, 1, 5, 3, 4, 7, 7
```

If we were to `^` them all together like this:

```
3 ^ 1 ^ 5 ^ 1 ^ 5 ^ 3 ^ 4 ^ 7 ^ 7
```

We can skip some of the math, and not worry about actually doing the hard work! We are able to do this because we have noticed something: each of the numbers appear either an odd number of times or an even number of times (DUH!). And we know some pretty cool rules about numbers that appear an even number of times, and numbers that appear an odd number of times.

We can rearrange the list to make it easier to count the number of occurrences of each particular number:

```
1 ^ 1 ^ 3 ^ 3 ^ 4 ^ 5 ^ 5 ^ 7 ^ 7
```

Remember we can do the rearranging because `^` is commutative.

Now we see that we have 2 `1`'s, 2 `3`'s, 1 `4`, 2 `5`'s, and 2 `7`'s.

Let's use our above rules to simplify our long list of math:

`1 ^ 1` becomes `0` so:

```
0 ^ 3 ^ 3 ^ 4 ^ 5 ^ 5 ^ 7 ^ 7
```

`3 ^ 3` becomes `0` so:

```
0 ^ 0 ^ 4 ^ 5 ^ 5 ^ 7 ^ 7
```

`5 ^ 5` becomes `0` so:

```
0 ^ 0 ^ 4 ^ 0 ^ 7 ^ 7
```

`7 ^ 7` becomes `0` so:

```
0 ^ 0 ^ 4 ^ 0 ^ 0
```

`0 ^ 0` becomes `0` (twice), so:

```
0 ^ 4 ^ 0
```

`0 ^ 4` becomes `4` (because `0 ^ n = n`) so:

`4 ^ 0` becomes `4` (because `n ^ 0 = n) so:

`4`

We didn't even do any actual math!

Now, if we had more than one number that was in the list an odd number of times, we would have had to do some math.

But if we have a list of numbers and each number is included an even number of times (be it 2 times, or 4, or 6, or any even number), it will break down to just `0`.

If we have a list of numbers and each number is included an even number of times, ***except*** for one number, it will break down to just that one number.

That is how the algorithm works. It cancels out the pairs of the same numbers, and is left with the one oddball.

The algorithm works because the list is guaranteed to have only one number appear once, and the rest appear twice. It still works as long as only one number appears any odd number of times, and every other number appears any even number of times.

You can see the math section below to see what's going on with the numbers.

After `^`'ing each number together, the pairs of same numbers cancelled out and became `0`, while the single numbers that couldn't be paired stayed the same.

Since we only had one number appear once, the rest could be paired so they became `0`.

The one odd number stayed and the rest became `0` so we essentially had: `n ^ 0` where `n` is the number that only appeared once.

And like we've said a time or two before, `n ^ 0 = n`!

So we took our list that had one number, `n`, which appeared an odd number of times, and found it by only using the `^` operator... and some slick rules.

---

> ## Explanation of the math

The `^` operator, or `XOR` operator, works with the binary representations of numbers.

Every number in binary is only 1's and 0's.

Let's look at the number, 5, and the number, 3:

```
5 = 101    and     3 = 11
```

If you don't know how I got these binary representations, read [this guide](http://ryanstutorials.net/binary-tutorial/) for your introduction.

Now, back to our binary numbers `101` and `11`.

We can do different operations like `&` or `|` which essentials mean AND and OR.

If we were to do the AND operation on `101` and `11`, we would do this:

```
  101
   11
&____
  001
```

We got 001 because we looked at the digit in each spot (the "ones" spot, the "tens" spot, and the "hundreds" spot). We compare them in each number. If both are `1`, then the result for that "spot" is a 1. Otherwise, it's a `0`.

So in the far left spot, or column, we compared the `1` in `101` with the blank in `11` and since both weren't `1`, we got `0`.
Then in the middle, we compared the `0` in `101` with the `1` in `11`, and we got `0` since both weren't `1`. Now in the right column, we compared the `1` in `101` with the `1` in `11`, and finally! We got a match! Both are `1` so we get a `1` in that spot.

No if we did the `|`, the OR operation, we would get this:

```
   101
    11
 &____
   111
```

That's because the `|` operator gives us `1` for a column if the number in *either* number is a `1` in that column. If both are `1`, we still get `1`.

---

### Now for the ^ operator

Now that we've seen how `&` and `|` work, let's talk about the `^` operator.

It's called XOR, and it is very similar to the AND and OR operators.
It gives us a `1` in a column if *either* number has a `1` in that column, but **not** both numbers.

For example, `1 ^ 0 = 1`   BUT   `1 ^ 1 = 0`. This is important!!!

The algorithm above does something very clever, and something that isn't particularly intuitive to most thinkers. It takes advantage of something. If any number is `^`'d with itself, you get 0 since they have the same `0`'s and `1`'s so they will always both have `1` in a certain column and therefore just come out to `0`.

Like this number:

```
   1010110110
   1010110110
 ^___________
   0000000000
```

See how each column we never have a `1` and a `0`, only either both `1`'s or both `0`'s.

Now it is hard to show, but if you play with enough numbers, you will realize that you can add in a number by `^`'ing it and take it out the same way. I don't mean add it to the value of total, but add it in.

---

### Imagine we are making a set!

We can add numbers to the set, but with this strange custom set, if we add in a number twice.. it disappears!

The `^` operator allows us to make this strange set!

From now on, I'll refer to this strange weird "set" as just set. It is not equivalent to a real set, but I think it's a convenient way to think about `^`. Just don't be confused when I say the word "set", I am only referring to this made up definition I use.

Let's look at the numbers: `1, 2, 3`.

If we take their binary representations we get:

```
1 = 1
2 = 10
3 = 11
```

If we start with 0 as our set, the binary representation is simply `0`.
Now let's `^` our `0` with any one of those numbers. Let's say 3.

```
     0 #our set
    11
 ^____
    11
```

Now we have `11` as our **set**, or our binary representation.

Remember if we `^` two of the same numbers together, we get `0`. This is true here too. We have `11` right now and if we `^` `11` with that, we'll be back to 0.

Now the crazy part is, we can `^` more than two numbers together, and our fact remains the same.

Right now we have added `3` to our set. Our set looks like this:

```
{3}
```

The binary representation of our set is:

```
11
```

Let's `^` another number to it. How about `1`?

```
  11  #our set
   1  #1
^____
  10
```

So now our set looks like this:

```
{3, 1} the binary representation is: 10
```

Our rule still applies about the `^` one number with itself `^`  to get 0. Let's see what happens when we try to `^` 3 with our set.

```
  10  #our set
  11  #3
^____
  01  #our new set
```

We took our set of `{3, 1} or 10` and `^`'d it with `3` and in essence we popped the three right out! Remember that our set will take out a number if we try to add it twice.

The old set:

```
{3, 1}
```

We tried to add 3, but it already existed so the set popped it out:

```
{1}
```

We can see this in our binary representation because it went from:

```
10
```

to

```
01
```

That's the same as just `1`!!! So we added 3, added 1, added 3, and got 1! That what `^` does! It will cancel out any pair of the same number.

We can see this with more and more numbers:

```
The list:
    3, 1, 5, 1, 5, 3, 4, 7, 7
```

The algorithm you gave starts with 0, and `^`'s each number onto what it has.

It essentially does this:

```
0 ^ 3 ^ 1 ^ 5 ^ 1 ^ 5 ^ 3 ^ 4 ^ 7 ^ 7
```

But to make this math more like the algorithm, I will show exactly what happens.

Start with `num = 0`

```
num = 0
num in binary = 0
```

Going through the list, we `^` each number. Let's get started!

`num ^= 3`

```
   0  #num
  11  #3
^____
  11  #new value for num

num = 3
num in binary = 11
```

`num ^= 1`

```
  11  #num
   1  #1
^____
  10  #new value for num

num = 2
num in binary = 10
```

`num ^= 5`

```
  10  #num
 101  #5
^____
 111  #new value for num

num = 7
num in binary = 111
```

`num ^= 5`

```
 111  #num
   1  #1
^____
 110  #new value for num

num = 6
num in binary = 110
```

`num ^= 5`

```
 110  #num
 101  #5
^____
 011  #new value for num

num = 3
num in binary = 011
```

`num ^= 3`

```
  11  #num
  11  #3
^____
  00  #new value for num

num = 0
num in binary = 0
```

`num ^= 5`

```
   0  #num
  10  #4
^____
  10  #new value for num

num = 4
num in binary = 10
```

`num ^= 7`

```
  10  #num
 111  #7
^____
 101  #new value for num

num = 5
num in binary = 101
```

`num ^= 7`

```
 101  #num
 111  #7
^____
 010  #new value for num

num = 4
num in binary = 010
```

After `^`'ing each number together, the pairs of same numbers cancelled out and became `0`, while the single numbers that couldn't be paired stayed the same.

Since we only had one number appear once, the rest could be paired so they became `0`.

The one odd number stayed and the rest became `0` so we essentially had: `n ^ 0` where `n` is the number that only appeared once.

And like we've said a time or two before, `n ^ 0 = n`!

So we took our list that had one number, `n`, which appeared an odd number of times, and found it by only using the `^` operator... and some slick rules.

#### So now we know the simple rules, and we know how the math actually works!

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 3):

The XOR operator in this case is effectively canceling out the values that appear twice, leaving only the number that appears once.

```
0 ^ 3 = 3 // first time
3 ^ 3 = 0 // second time
```

Think of XOR ("exclusive or") as removing everything in common between two values.  [More on XOR.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or)

Comment: Just like to add that this only works if all the other numbers appear an even number of times.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for the effect that you see is the fact that XOR of a number with itself always produces a zero, and XOR's [*commutativity*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) - i.e. the fact that the order in which you pick operands from a list does not change the outcome of the operation.

It is easy to see that if arrange your list

```
    A ^ B ^ C ^ B ^ A ^ D ^ C
```

in a way that all identical pairs are next to each other

```
    A ^ A ^ B ^ B ^ C ^ C ^ D
```

you could group the list as follows:

```
    (A ^ A) ^ (B ^ B) ^ (C ^ C) ^ D
--  -------   -------   -------
--    zero      zero      zero
```

Hence the result is `D`, i.e. the only value that is not repeated in the original list. Due to XORs commutativity, the result is going to be the same regardless of the order in which XOR is applied.